# Setting text of element using jQuery .data() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have some HTML table cells which have data attributes called `data-rawdate` containing a full (and ugly-looking) datetime value rendered from the server. Using jQuery, I want to take that raw date string, format it using a date library (in this case, Moment.js), and set that as the text of the `<td>`.

Here's a simplified version, [along with a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stamminator/z3s6rd08/).

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-rawdate="1/6/2016 9:39:29 AM" class="dateField"></td>
    <td class="otherField"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-rawdate="1/6/2016 9:58:31 AM" class="dateField"></td>
    <td class="otherField"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-rawdate="1/6/2016 10:01:17 AM" class="dateField"></td>
    <td class="otherField"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".dateField").text(
    moment($(this).data("rawdate"), "M-D-YYYY h:m:s a")
        .format("M/D/YYYY")
  );

  //$(".dateField").text($(this).data("rawdate"));
});
```

At first I thought it was an issue with the library, Moment.js, but then I tried skipping the formatting and simply setting the element's text to `$(this).data("rawdate")` (see the commented line of JS), and even that didn't work. I even tried `.attr("data-rawdate")` instead of `.data("rawdate")`—nothing.

Does anyone know why the `.text()` function doesn't seem to be liking the `.data()` function? Thanks.

Comment: What do you think `this` is in your call to `moment()`? Hint: it's not the current table cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method and set text in callback function of `each`. See example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".dateField").each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).data("rawdate"));
  });
;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-rawdate="1/6/2016 9:39:29 AM" class="dateField"></td>
    <td class="otherField"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-rawdate="1/6/2016 9:58:31 AM" class="dateField"></td>
    <td class="otherField"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-rawdate="1/6/2016 10:01:17 AM" class="dateField"></td>
    <td class="otherField"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So your code from question:

```
$(".dateField").text(
    moment($(this).data("rawdate"), "M-D-YYYY h:m:s a")
        .format("M/D/YYYY")
  );
```

Were changed to:

```
$(".dateField").each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).data("rawdate"));
  });
```

There are no `moment()`, but problem isn't in it. The main idea is that how you accessing and interact with elements.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer, this makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".dateField").each(function(){
    $(this).text(moment($(this).data("rawdate"), "M-D-YYYY h:m:s a").format("M/D/YYYY")));
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course—my selector wasn't iterative, but was looking the the whole result set. Thanks, this does the trick :)